# Change reading rate and text string of "Post Time to Read" core block

Tags: block-editor

How do I change the reading rate and text string in the "Post Time to Read" core block.

- Reading rate - to be changed to 200
- Text string - 'minute' and 'minutes' to be changed to 'min read'

Link to file - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-time-to-read/index.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Server-side rendering of the `core/post-time-to-read` block.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     */
    
    /**
     * Renders the `core/post-time-to-read` block on the server.
     *
     * @param  array    $attributes Block attributes.
     * @param  string   $content    Block default content.
     * @param  WP_Block $block      Block instance.
     * @return string Returns the rendered post author name block.
     */
    function render_block_core_post_time_to_read( $attributes, $content, $block ) {
        if ( ! isset( $block->context['postId'] ) ) {
            return '';
        }
    
        $content = get_the_content();
    
        /*
         * Average reading rate - based on average taken from
         * https://irisreading.com/average-reading-speed-in-various-languages/
         * (Characters/minute used for Chinese rather than words).
         */
        $average_reading_rate = 189;
    
        $word_count_type = wp_get_word_count_type();
    
        $minutes_to_read = max( 1, (int) round( wp_word_count( $content, $word_count_type ) / $average_reading_rate ) );
    
        $minutes_to_read_string = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s is the number of minutes the post will take to read. */
            _n( '%s minute', '%s minutes', $minutes_to_read ),
            $minutes_to_read
        );
    
        $align_class_name = empty( $attributes['textAlign'] ) ? '' : "has-text-align-{$attributes['textAlign']}";
    
        $wrapper_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes( array( 'class' => $align_class_name ) );
    
        return sprintf(
            '<div %1$s>%2$s</div>',
            $wrapper_attributes,
            $minutes_to_read_string
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Registers the `core/post-time-to-read` block on the server.
     */
    function register_block_core_post_time_to_read() {
        register_block_type_from_metadata(
            __DIR__ . '/post-time-to-read',
            array(
                'render_callback' => 'render_block_core_post_time_to_read',
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_block_core_post_time_to_read' );
```